# Spring-data : select distinct of a "sub class"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here is my model:

```
@Entity
Class SubClass {
    ...
}

@Entity
Class MainClass {
    ...
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    private SubClass subClass;
    ...
}
```

With the use of jpa data, I would like to have a select distinct of the `SubClass`.
I tried to do that with a repository:

```
public interface MainClassRepository extends JpaRepository<MainClass, Integer> {
    public List<SubClass> findDistinctSubClassByName(String name);
}
```

The error I have as a result is the following:

```
 org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [MainClass] to type [SubClass]
```

I tried to create a Converter and add it as an entity, but Spring doesn't know it.

How can I do what I want? Either by registering my converter in the good place, or by doing something else that I haven't tought of yet?

Thanks!

Comment: create a repository for SubClass

Comment: I got one also. Do you mean by that that I should make a function in the SubClassRepository that does findDistinctByMainClassName or something like that ?

Comment: yes, i would go this way